# Unpack class variables

Tags: python-3.x, class

With collections.namedtuple one can make a `Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')` and set `p = Point(2,3)`, and unpack `p` using `x, y = p`.

Can something similar be done with classes? e.g

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x ,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
p = Point(2,3)
x,y = p
print(f"x: {x}, y: {y}")
>>> x: 2, y: 3
```

This would result in an error of course, but how can one get the effect of the namedtuple?

Comment: tl;dr: Implement `__iter__`

Comment: You could but in most cases it would be an odd thing to do with a class. A tuple is immutable so the mapping between named key and index is also immutable. Classes generally don't offer the same guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._flag = 2
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._flag == 2:
            self._flag = 1
            return self.x
        elif self._flag == 1:
            self._flag = 0
            return self.y
        else:
            raise StopIteration()


p = Point(5, 6)

(x, y) = p
```

Comment: `class Point(tuple):` instead gives me `tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Answer (score -1):

To get the effect of named tuple make your class a subclass of tuple.
See my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040586/write-class-such-that-calling-instance-returns-all-instance-variables) and answer