# Write class such that calling instance returns all instance variables

Tags: python-3.x, class, return, subclass, subclassing

**I have answered my own question - see answer below**
I'm writing a class, and I want this behavior:

```
a = f(10,20)
some_funct(a.row) # some_function is given 10
some_funct(a.col) # some_function is given 20
some_funct(a)     # some_function is given a tuple of 10, 20  <-- THIS ONE :)
```

The last behavior is stumping me. I have not seen any examples that cover this.

Thus far:

```
class f(object):
    """Simple 2d object"""
    row: int
    col: int

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
```

Explictly I do not want another method, say, self.both = row, col.
I just want to 'call' the instance

I'm new to classes, so any improvements are welcome. Properties, setters, getters etc.

EDIT 1:
Replaced "print" with "some_function" in the question, and modified title

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```py
class f(object):
    """Simple 2d object"""
    row: int
    col: int

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        return f"row = {row}, col = {col}"
```

and print like this

```py
a = f(10,20)

print(a)     # row = 10, col = 20
```

Comment: Thank you Hillal, this does not suit my needs but my question was confusing. I have modified my question to remove the confusing print call.

Answer (score 0):

From python 3.7 [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) have been introduced and their goal is to create classes that mainly contains data. Dataclasses comes with some helper function that extract the class attributes dict/tuples. e.g.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,asdict,astuple
@dataclass
class f:
 x: int
 y: int

f_instance = f(10,20)
asdict(f_instance) # --> {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
astuple(f_instance) # -> (10,20)
```

EDIT I : Another technique would be to use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) e.g.:

```
from collections import namedtuple
f = namedtuple('p',['row','col'])
a =f(10,20)
a.row #-> 10
a.col #-> 20
```

Comment: print(f_instance) returns <class '__main__.f'>.
I need it to return (10,20)

Comment: As written you need to use the astuple function i.e. `astuple(f_instance)` and this will return `(10,20)`

Comment: Perhaps an alternative question. If I assign x = 1 I can simply print(x) and it works the way I want in my question. How is the 'x' class implemented so I can use that in my class to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Maybe `named tuple` should work ?

`from collections import namedtuple
f = namedtuple('p',['row','col'])
a =f(10,20)
a.row #--> 10
a.col # --> 20`

Comment: Could you show the complete written class please

Comment: I have edited my answer, everything is there. You create a named tuple assigning a property name and then you can create instances of this named tuple and access its properties e.g. `(a.row,a.col) = (10,20)`

Comment: Please see my answer which gives tuple behavior. Thank you for your efforts <br> can't up vote my own answer though :/

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```py
class f(object):
    """Simple 2d object"""
    row: int
    col: int

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def some_funct(self):
        return (self.row, self.col)
```

You can access like

```py
a = f(10,20)
a.some_funct() # (10, 20)
# or
row, col = a.some_funct()
```

Comment: ah yes, I'm currently using this method solution of def some_funct, I find it somewhat ugly in my code.
Perhaps an alternative question. If I assign x = 1 I can simply print(x) and it works the way I want in my question. How is the 'x' class implemented so I can use that in my class to achieve the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
class f(tuple):
    """Simple 2d object"""
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return tuple.__new__(f, (x, y))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.col = x
        self.row = y

foo = f(1,2)
print(foo.col)
>>>1
print(foo.row)
>>>2
print(foo)
>>>(1, 2)
```

Importantly:
If you want it to behave like a tuple then make it a subclass of tuple.

Much stuffing around but stumbled upon an [external site](https://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subclass-int.html) which gave me clues about the keywords to search on here. The SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments) but I have modified that answer slightly.
I'm still a little confused because the other site says to use **new** in the init as well but does not give a clear example.